# sympy - can't make nsolve method work

Tags: python, sympy, mpmath

I did this code:

```
from scitools.std import *
from sympy import *

x=Symbol('x')
#Integral function
#def f(x):             --> I also tried this
 #   return exp(-x**2)

f=exp(-x**2)

intac=integrate(f,(x,0,1))
print(nsolve(f,x,1))
```

The interpreter gives me: "local variable x referenced before assignment"

If I try `nsolve(f,x,(0,1))` it gives me: "could not find root within given tolerance..."

(Also, I tried `findroot(f,(0,1))` without any success (I imported `from mpmath import *` and then `mp.dps = 30; mp.pretty = True`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about nsolve's call syntax, but I can tell you why neither sympy nor mpmath can find a real root of the function: there aren't any.  If f(x)=exp(-x^2), then f(x) > 0 for any real x.  f(0) = 1 and the function decreases as abs(x) gets bigger in either direction, but it's always positive.  Certainly there's no root in [0,1].

It might be worthwhile reading up on [the normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Integrating it seems to work as it should:

```
>>> integrate(f,(x,0,1))
    pi**(1/2)*erf(1)/2
```

Comment: :Yes ,you are right!I totally missed it!But how can i have a numeric value from this? "integrate(f,(x,0,1))" This gives me the "pi**(1/2)*erf(1)/2".I want a number.

Comment: @George use .evalf() on it (eg. integrate(f,(x,0,1)).evalf() ).